# Central european characters in SQL

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have an issue. I have data stored on SQL server with central european characters like `"č", "ř", "ž"` etc. On the database I have the "Czech_CI_AS" collation which should accepted these characters. But when I try to select for example name of the street with this characters like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Street where Name = 'Čáslavská'
```

It returns me nothing 
When I remove the "č" it returns me what I need.

```
SELECT *
FROM Street where Name like '%áslavská'
```

I have this column in `nvarchar` type. But I cannot use the N character before my string because the external applications use this table for read and selects are made automaticlly.

Is here any solution? Or have I got something wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you see the same collation `Czech_CI_AS` both in the properties of the database and in the properties of column `Name`?

Comment: Speaking of the correct SQL approach you have to use N char before strings. If you don't.. If I were you, I'd look to the way of replacing specific characters into standard English alphabet

Comment: @soldous I did a quick test with a new table with an nvarchar column with collation Czech_CI_AS but could not reproduce your problem; your query seems to work fine, even uppercase `Č` versus lowercase `č`. Could you please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

@YuriyTsarkov really deservers the credit here.  To elaborate on his answer.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186939.aspx):

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

**Example**

```
-- Storing Čáslavská in two vars, with and without N prefix.
DECLARE @Test_001 NVARCHAR(255)  =  'Čáslavská' COLLATE Czech_CI_AS;
DECLARE @Test_002 NVARCHAR(255)  = N'Čáslavská' COLLATE Czech_CI_AS;

-- Test output.
SELECT 
    @Test_001   AS T1,
    @Test_002   AS T2
;
```

Returns

```
T1         T2
Cáslavská  Čáslavská
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update all your external applications code to use selects with N, or, you need to change collation of your column to same, as used by external applications. It may cause some data loss.